# If $x^4 \equiv -1 \mod p$ then $p \equiv 1 \mod 8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While learning about the Legendre symbol I came across this fact:

> If $x^ 4 \equiv -1 \mod p$ then $p \equiv 1 \mod 8$.

Provided '$p$' is a prime greater than $2$.

I could not prove it. Can someone help me to prove the same?

Thanks.

Comment: $p$ is a prime.?

Comment: It is a prime. Else the $p\equiv 2 / 1 \mod 8$

Comment: $p$ prime must be given as assumption. Since $3^4 \equiv -1 \textrm{ mod} 82$, and 82 is not a prime.

Comment: p is a prime number

Comment: You need to specify that $p$ is odd. Note that $1^4 \equiv -1 \pmod{2}$.

Answer (score 14):

Let $p$ be a prime. 
Suppose that $x^4+1\equiv 0 \textrm{ mod }p$ is solvable.

Then 
$x$ has order 8 in the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Since an order of subgroup must divide the group order, and the cyclic group generated by $x$ has order $8$, we have $8\mid p-1$.

Comment: And since the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_p$ is itself always cyclic, one has $x^4\equiv1\pmod p$ solvable for an odd prime $p$ _if and_ only if $p\equiv1\pmod8$. (But of course that was not the question.)