# For an odd prime $p$, prove that the congruence $2x^2 +1 \equiv 0\pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $p ≡ 1 \text{ or } 3\pmod 8$

Tags: number-theory

I have to prove that the congruence $2x^2 +1 ≡ 0\pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $p ≡ 1 \text{ or } 3\pmod 8$, for any odd prime.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333587/if-x4-equiv-1-mod-p-then-p-equiv-1-mod-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want $-2$ to be a square modulo $p$. In fact a solution $x$ exists if and only if $ x^{2} \equiv (-2)/4$ is a square modulo $p$, and thus if and only if $-2$ is a square modulo $p$.

This is because the following congruences modulo $p$ are equivalent: (reworked avoiding inverses at a suggestion of Math Gems in the comments)

- $2 x^2 + 1 \equiv 0$
- $2 x^{2} \equiv -1$
- $(2 x)^{2} \equiv - 2$

Now
$$
\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)
 \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)
$$
is $1$ [if and only if $p \equiv 1, 3 \pmod{8}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#The_supplementary_laws_using_Legendre_symbols).

Comment: The first part is what I wanted to know how is 2x^2+1=0(mod p) same as x^2 = -2 (mod p)

Comment: @noddy, is it clear now? $2 x^2 + 1 \equiv 0$ is the same as $2 x^{2} \equiv -1$ which is the same as $x^{2} \equiv - 2^{-1} \equiv (-2) (2^{-1})^{2}$, where $2^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $2$ modulo the odd prime $p$.

Comment: yah..had initially missed the inverse part..Thanks

Comment: @noddy, you're welcome.

Comment: infact using the technique even k*x^2+1=0(mod p) can be solved in a similar way;k would be invertible since p is a prime

Comment: @noddy $\rm\ mod\ p\!:\ -1 \equiv kx^2\:\Rightarrow -k\equiv k^2 x^2 \equiv (kx)^2.\:$ Note that one does not need to use inverses to make that inference. It is squareness, not invertibility, that plays the key role.

Comment: @MathGems, quite right, I have edited accordingly, with proper credit.